# Is the following proof for the compactness of set A correct and rigorous?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that the sets $J,K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are both nonempty and compact. Rigorously prove that the set $A=\{x+y: x \in J, y \in K\}$ is also compact.

**One way to prove this statement is the following. Is this correct, complete in all its steps and rigorous?**

Consider any open cover $(U_i)_i$ of $J+K$. Now, for each $k \in K$, $J+\{k\}$ is a compact set (just the translation of a compact set, which is again compact) that is contained in $J+K$, so we can extract a finite subsequence of open sets of the covering $(U_i)_i$ that covers $J+\{k\}$.

Now, using the compactness of $K$, we try to prove that it is enough to consider these finite coverings for a finite number of $k \in K$ in order to cover $J+K$.
If $k_1,...k_n$ is such a finite number of elements of $K$, we have that $J+K$ is contained in the union of the finite coverings associated to each $J+\{k_i\}$. Since it is a finite union of finite collections of open sets, we obtain a finite covering for $J+K$.

Having obtained a finite collection of open sets of $(U_i)_i$ that covers $J+k$, we have proved that $J+K$, and thus $A$, is compact.

Comment: This is not correct no, you prove that *if* you can find such a collection of elements from $K$, then the set is compact. You never prove that you can actually find such a collection

Comment: How can I prove that we can actually find such a collection?

Answer (score 1):

Carlyle's comment that there is a gap between the two parts of the proof is on point. A reasonable way to do bridge it would be:

For $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ a cover of $J+K$, taking finite subcovers $\{U_i\}_{i \in I_k}$ of $J + {k}$ [ for $I_k \subseteq I$ depending on $k$ ], as you did, translate each of them over to $K$, that is, consider $\{(U-J)_i\}_{i \in I_k}$, and notice the union is a cover of $K$, then by compactness there is a finite subcover, involving only some $k_1,...k_n$, so that $\{U_i\}_{i \in I_{k_1}}\cup \ ... \ \cup \{U_i\}_{i \in I_{k_n}}$ is the finite subcover for $J+K$